# No error in code but the data is not being written in output txt

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I tried to write a code for my assignment. It is not showing any error but when I read input from the file, save them in array of object and then, I'm trying to put write values to an output file. the data is of that object which I want to write but nothing is being written in the output txt. I cant find the problem.

> **The input txt file format**

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | //number of students |
| 3 | // number of grades (per student) |
| Student1 99 87 90 | // / name grade grade grade |
| Student2 50 67 95 |  |

**Code is written below**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Student
{
private:
    string name;
    int grade1;
    int grade2;
    int grade3;
    float avg;
public:
    Student()
    {
        name = "\0";
        grade1 = grade2 = grade3 = avg = 0;
    }
    void setname(string Name)
    {
        name = Name;
    }
    void setgrade1(int num)
    {
        grade1 = num;
    }
    void setgrade2(int num)
    {
        grade2 = num;
    }
    void setgrade3(int num)
    {
        grade3 = num;
    }
    void AVG()
    {
        avg = (grade1 + grade2 + grade3) / 3;
    }
    float getAVG()
    {
        return avg;
    }
    string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

};

int main()
{
    char ch = '\0';
    char pre = '\0';
    Student S[3];
    int totalstudents = 0;
    int totalgrades = 0;
    cout << "Enter file name including " ", e.g \"myFile.txt\" :"  << endl;
    string file;
    cin >> file;
    fstream myFile;
    int loop = 0;
    int loop2 = 0;
    myFile.open(file);
    {
        while (myFile.get(ch))
        {
            if (loop != 1)
            {
                myFile >> totalstudents >> totalgrades;
                loop++;
            }
            string namE;
            int g1, g2, g3;
            myFile >> namE >> g1 >> g2 >> g3;
            S[loop2].setname(namE);
            S[loop2].setgrade1(g1);
            S[loop2].setgrade2(g2);
            S[loop2].setgrade3(g3);
            S[loop2].AVG();
            loop2++;
            if (loop2 == totalstudents)
                break;
        }
    }
    myFile.close();
    fstream myFile2;
    myFile2.open("fout.txt");
    {
        for (int loop = 0; loop < totalstudents; loop++)
        {
            myFile << S[loop].getName() << "\t" << S[loop].getAVG() << endl;
        }
    };
    myFile2.close();
    _getch();

}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to figure out what your code is doing. Don't just run your code in the debugger, step through your code 1 line at a time looking at the variables and flow at each step.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (myFile.get(ch))
```

`get()` reads one character from the file. It is has now been read, never to be read again. Unfortunately, the subsequent code still expects the initial contents to be there, which it expects to read from this point on.

This is the fundamental logical error that fails to produce the expected results. You will need to completely redesign the input reading part of the problem, in order to fix the incorrect logic.

For some reason the current logic crams the code that reads the initial  `totalstudents` and `totalgrades` as part of the loop that reads each student's data. This unnecessarily complicates the logic. Simply reading this, first, followed by a single loop to read each students data, should be sufficient. Unfortunately there are additional fundamental issues with the shown code that will require a more complete overhaul, in order to fix them properly.

The shown code can only handle no more than three students' data, and is hardcoded to handle exactly three grades for each student.

It seems clear to be from the description of the assignment that your program should handle ***any*** number of students, 2 students, 3 students, or a 100 students; and ***any*** number of grades per student, and not always three grades exactly. Otherwise there would be no reason, whatsoever, to provide these values in the input data.

Unfortunately, this is not possible using the current program's class, and logic, and this will also need to be addressed as well.